# Find out if a word can be the start of a word in a dictionary

Tags: java, string, collections

I have to find out if a given word can be the start of other words in a dictionary.

I implemented the dictionary by using TreeSet.

TreeSet dictionary
   String startString;

**Problem 1**

What's the most efficient way to find out if `startString` is the start o at a least a word in the dictionary?

**Idea 1**

My idea is to use `dictionary.subSet(startString, startStringPlusOne);`

Where `startStringPlusOne` is equals to `startString` except for the last character, which is the following one in the alphabet.

Example:

```
startString: hom
startStringPlusOne: hon
```

In this way it `SubSet` returns an empty set this means that `string` is not the start of a word in the dictionary.

**Problem 2**

What's the most efficient way for computing stringPlusOne?

**Idea 2**

I thought to use an array of chars with the alphabet letters and replace the last letter of `string` with the following char in the array.
Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Can't you just use: - `stringPlusOne.startsWith(string)`?

Comment: `char nextChar = (char) (currentChar + 1);`. No need for an array.

Comment: I guess a trie would be what you need if you are looking for an efficent solution.

Comment: @JBNizet That's a good idea. I had to put a control for 'z', beacuse the ('z' + 1) is not 'a'. Thanks

Comment: @RohitJain Sorry, I didn't understand your solution. Can you be more explicit please. thanks in advance

Comment: This seems like a really neat solution, on the control for 'z' comment above, I don't think you need it (unless I've misunderstood what you're planning to do), if you had string: hoz, then you'd get stringPlusOne: ho{ which would be the next string, albeit not a 'real' word. If you changed it to stringPlusOne: hoa, that wouldn't work.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave You are right, if string is "hoz" than stringPlusOne should be "hpa"

Answer (score 1):

If memory is not a concern, I'd be tempted to store two dictionaries. Into one you put your words, into another you put your word beginnings.

```
1)
["aardvark", "banana", "band"]

2)
{
    "aardvar" => 1,
    "aardva" => 1,
    "aardv" => 1,
    "aard" => 1, 
    "aar" => 1, 
    "aa" => 1, 
    "a" => 1, 
    "banan" => 1, 
    "bana" => 1, 
    "ban" => 2, 
    "ba" => 2, 
    "b" => 2
}
```

So the answer to the question "Are there any words beginning with 'ban'?" is "Yes, there are 2". Your question doesn't say if it would then be necessary to find out which words those are.

The count is only really useful if you are ever required to remove words from the dictionary. If so, you will need to decrement the count and remove keys when they reach 0. If you don't need to do this, then you don't need to store the number.

If you need to answer the question "Which words start with 'ban'?", then you'll need to store references to those words instead of just a count, e.g.

```
"ban" => ["banana", "band"]
```

This would seem to be the most efficient in terms of speed, at the expense of efficiency in terms of memory (Which may not be a concern worth worrying about).

Comment: Probably it is not clear from my question but I have to find out if a string can be the start of some words in my dictionary or not. Doesn't matter how much, neither which one. I just have to know if at least one word start with the same chars stores in `string`. I have a dictionary that contains more than 200000 words. I don't think that create a second dictionary with all the beginnings is efficient. Not in terms of Memory, neither in terms of research time. Do you agree?

Comment: Think of it as a large cache in the form of a giant lookup table. You take your substring and do a single lookup with a yes/no answer. Doesn't get much more efficient than that.

Comment: So you are advising me to create two `TreeSet`s, one for the dictionary and one for the beginnings. I suppose it would be at least 5 times greater than the dictionary. Do you think that the execution of `beginnings.contains(key)` is faster that `dictionary.subSet(string,strinPlusOne).size>0`?

Comment: I'd imagine so. The only authorative way to to answer that though is to test it.